# Pylint error not-an-iterable in match case

Tags: python, match, generator, pylint, iterable

I have 2 functions that do the same thing: recursively iterate an object and return all the string values. I would prefer to use iter2, with the match case, as it is easier on the eye. They both run correctly but pylint reports errors in the second function.

```
def iter1(object_):
    if isinstance(object_, str):
        yield object_
    if isinstance(object_, list):
        for item in object_:
            yield from iter1(item)
    elif isinstance(object_, dict):
        for value in object_.values():
            yield from iter1(value)
    return

def iter2(object_):
    match object_:
        case str():
            yield object_
        case list():
            for item in object_:
                yield from iter2(item)
        case dict():
            for value in object_.values():
                yield from iter2(value)
        case _:
            return

aaa = {"a": "abc", "b": "123", "c": ["def", "ghi", "jkl"], "d": {"e": "mno", "f": ["pqr", "stu"]}}
print(list(iter1(aaa)))
print(list(iter2(aaa)))
```

Both produce the same output.

```
['abc', '123', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']
['abc', '123', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']
```

But pylint reports these errors in the function iter2.

```
Non-iterable value iter2(item) is used in an iterating context pylint (not-an-iterable)
Non-iterable value iter2(value) is used in an iterating context pylint (not-an-iterable)
```

at these lines:

```
yield from iter2(item)
yield from iter2(value)
```

---

I have logged it as a [bug on pylint's github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5845)

Comment: So,  `pylint` is wrong. Ignore its complaint, or if it bothers you that much, add a comment to  suppress it.

Comment: Could you give the output of ``pylint --version`` ?

Comment: @BoarGules Duh, I'm only pointing it out.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas  `pylint 2.12.2
astroid 2.9.3  
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: Why point it out on SO? This is not the venue for a `pylint` bug report.

Comment: @BoarGules: Well first of all I wanted to check if it was actually a bug or maybe I was doing something stupid, and second of all I went to the pylint homepage and could not see a way of reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by `Pylint` and the `not-an-iterable` messages are no longer emitted for this code. The fix is available since [version 2.17.0](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.17/index.html#id23) (release date: March 8 2023).